# Yesod respondSource from source that has PrimMonad constraint

Tags: haskell, yesod, conduit

I am working on a website using Yesod and am trying to stream  a file from a zip archive into the HTTP response.

I choose the `zip` package, the relevant function is [getEntrySource](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-1.2.0/docs/Codec-Archive-Zip.html#v:getEntrySource).

It returns a

```
ConduitT () ByteString m ()
```

where `m` has to satisfy

- `PrimMonad m`
- `MonadThrow m`
- `MonadResource m`

One type that would fit those constraints would be `ResourceT IO`

In order to stream data Yesod provides the [respondSource](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.0/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:respondSource) function that takes a

`ConduitT () (Flush Builder) (HandlerFor site) ()`

My Problem is:

- `ResourceT IO` would work for `getEntrySource` but `respondSource` expects a `HandlerFor site`. I found the `transPipe` function but I don't think unwrapping the `ResourceT IO` and wrapping every chunk in a `HandlerFor site` is what I want.
- `HandlerFor site` isn't an instance of `PrimMonad` and I don't grasp `PrimMonad` enough to judge whether it would even make sense for it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a pure oversight that `HandlerFor` isn't an instance of `PrimMonad`. I've [pushed a commit](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/commit/55e0ca4bc387408e9026c5fc10eb54916bf48522) that should address this, and will release to Hackage once CI tells me it's safe.